# Docker LXC driver vs libcontainer

Tags: docker, lxc

I have read about, that `Docker` has changed its driver in last iteration. What are main differences if don't keep eyes on performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between LXC and libcontainer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34152365/difference-between-lxc-and-libcontainer)