# Difference between LXC and libcontainer

Tags: docker, lxc

While going through docker docs, I found that docker is now using libcontainer instead of LXC. Has anyone idea about how libcontainer is better (if so..) than LXC ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

- [Linux Containers (LXC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) was used before docker 0.9 (On [March 13, 2014, with the release of version 0.9](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/), Docker dropped LXC as the default execution environment and replaced it with its own libcontainer library) as one execution driver by docker, and offered a  userspace interface for the Linux kernel containment features. It is very specific to Linux
- libcontainer (now [`opencontainers/runc`](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc)) is an abstraction, in order to support a wider range of isolation technologies as [described in this article](http://jancorg.github.io/blog/2015/01/03/libcontainer-overview/)

[image: http://blog.docker.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/docker-execdriver-diagram.png]

That means **Docker is abstracting itself from its original implementation, allowing other vendors (like CoreOS) to implement their own version of containers**.

---

Note: since then ([What’s the difference between runc, containerd, docker?](https://medium.com/@alenkacz/whats-the-difference-between-runc-containerd-docker-3fc8f79d4d6e)) shows:

> In 2016 the container space was booming and docker decided to split the monolith into separate parts, some of which other projects can even build on — that’s how **[`containerd`](https://blog.docker.com/2016/04/docker-containerd-integration/)** happened. That was Docker 1.11 (so pretty much ancient history).
>   Containerd is a daemon that acts as API facade for various container runtimes and OS. When using `containerd,` you no longer work with syscalls, instead you work with higher-level entities like snapshot and container — the rest is abstracted away.
>   If you want to understand `containerd` even more in depth, there’s a [design documentation](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/tree/master/design) in their GitHub repo.
>   **Under the hood, `containerd` uses `runc` to do all the linux work**.

See more at "[How containerd compares to runC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41645665/6309)"

[image: containerd]

Comment: question was about libcontainer, not about libnetwork

Comment: @ISanych right, I'll rewrite the answer then

Comment: @VonC thanks for the reply. It means that, now docker has namespaces, cgroups ( from LXC ) and additional kernel features selinux, netlink, capabilities etc coming from libcontainer. Am I right VonC ?

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar yes, that is what the SPEC mentions (https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/b741e3dc9da048b9f2393cb7ff3043a2fba36618/libcontainer/SPEC.md: amespaces, standard filesystem setup, a default Linux capability set, and information about resource reservations)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend you to go through this link to have a complete understanding of why Docker started libcontainer

http://www.zdnet.com/article/docker-libcontainer-unifies-linux-container-powers/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I am aware.. LXC was default execution driver for docker engine to execute its container/namespace and other. Docker developed 'libcontainer' and added to their docker engine. Correct me if I am wrong.