# Questions about how docker daemon initializes the seccomp filter

Tags: docker, seccomp

I read the original code of the moby project and read the seccomp code in the `moby/profiles` folder.
I know that docker use the libseccomp-golang to support the feature.

We usually use the `libseccomp.NewFilter()` API to create a seccomp filter. However, I can't see any API in the libseccomp was involved in the project except the `libseccomp.GetNativeArch()` which can be seen in the

```
moby/profiles/seccomp/seccomp.go
```

So I am wondering how does the docker daemon initialize the seccomp filter for each container? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> So I am wondering how does the docker daemon initialize the seccomp filter for each container?

The **docker daemon** calls **containerd** which then calls **runc**.

The **seccomp filter** is installed by **runc** [here](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/9524366183517b379a1fca8b9b250002ba3b1be7/libcontainer/standard_init_linux.go#L207) using the **InitSeccomp** method, you can find the definition of **InitSeccomp** [here](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/main/libcontainer/seccomp/seccomp_linux.go).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645665/how-containerd-compares-to-runc) question can give you a high level overview of how **runc** is used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).