# Kubernetes `RuntimeHandler "runc" not supported` when creating container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I was trying to specify the `runtime` of containers deployed using Kubernetes. I follow the guide in [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/#upgrading-runtimeclass-from-alpha-to-beta) and creating the following `RuntimeClass`:

```yaml
apiVersion: node.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RuntimeClass
metadata:
    name: runc
handler: runc

# $ kubeclt get RuntimeClass
# NAME   HANDLER   AGE
# runc   runc      59m
```

Then, I set my Pod `spec.runtimeClassName="runc"`. However, when deploying this using Kubernetes, I got the following error:

```
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m43s (x141 over 32m)  kubelet, jetson1   Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = RuntimeHandler "runc" not supported
```

I can run the container with `docker` and `--runtime=runc` without any error. But when deploying it with K8s, the error occur. The following is my `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 11
  Running: 5
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 6
 Images: 12
 Server Version: 19.03.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: nvidia runc
 Default Runtime: nvidia
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.9.140-tegra
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.871GiB
 Name: jetson1
 ID: HLZ4:DQKM:J7YY:OMDN:JXXZ:PFL5:YJGT:DJBM:SMSL:UTZA:WCZ4:GUD4
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How did you configure runtime handlers?

Comment: @Hanx, I just use the default `runc` handler in docker and did not modify anything.

Answer (score 2):

While runc is able to create containers, it's a rather low-level component. Most tools we know as container runtimes actually rely on it in some way. [This answer to another question gives a great overview of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645665/how-containerd-compares-to-runc).

The RuntimeClass feature in Kubernetes to target a specific conainer runtime requires it to implement the CRI (Container Runtime Interface) on the local nodes (the "Setup" part of your shared link briefly talks about it). I did some quick research and there is no hint that runc is implementing CRI directly. If it was, Kubernetes would skip accessing Docker as you did; it would use that interface to talk to another component directly from kubelet. Checking Docker settings therefore doesn't help to see if runc is a viable Kubernetes container runtime.

So, you should review why you're trying to do this - runc is likely already used in your default container rumtime stack without you maybe realizing it. Kubernetes has documentation [for alternative container runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/), you can look into installing these if you are looking for something more lightweight than Docker.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The reason for doing this is I set my default docker runtime as `nvidia` to allow the containers to access GPU resource on the node. But for some containers I don't want it to be able to access the GPU, so I want to set the runtime back to `runc`.